# CentOS systemctl access denied

Tags: centos, root, access-denied, systemctl

I would disable *Ctrl-Alt-Delete* in my CentOS server so I tried:

```
systemctl mask ctrl-alt-delete.target
```

but I got:

```
Failed to execute operation: Access Denied
```

What can I do ?
PS: I'm root on the server

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when you try to enable a service that does not exist, but is not specific to 'systemctl mask ctrl-alt-delete.target':

```
> systemctl enable blabla
Failed to execute operation: Access denied
```

Looks like this is a Centos / Fedora etc. issue.

If you run 'setenforce 0' you will get a better error:

```
> setenforce 0
> systemctl enable blabla
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

**Don't forget to re-enable:**

```
> setenforce 1
> getenforce
Enforcing
```

In Ubuntu you will get the above error without running setenforce 0

Answer (score 2):

Please execute the following commands in order:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reexec
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

During the upgrade of Debian or Ubuntu server you may encounter strange failing of scripts which are restarting services.

For some reason it’s not possible to call systemcl and any operation fails with Access denied even for root.

Here is example:

```
systemctl list-units
Failed to list units: Access denied
```

The fix to this problem it is sufficient to send TERM signal to process with PID #1:

```
kill -TERM 1
```

Credits: https://georgik.rocks/systemctl-failed-to-list-units-access-denied/

Answer (score 0):

i have meet it in arch linux, when i use common user to run systemctl enable, it's like Access denied, when i use a root user to run it's, i resolve it, place.

Answer (score -1):

Run below command and try again. We will be found a new way if this not worked

```
su -
```

Comment: "PS: I'm root on the server" - under root

Answer (score -1):

Use **systemctl daemon-reexec**

It's safer than *setenforce 0*